# $\exp(-|x|^\alpha),\alpha>2$ is not a Fourier transform of a probability distribution

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Problem:

> Show that $\exp(-|x|^\alpha),\alpha>2$ is not a Fourier transform of a probability distribution

Hint:

> What would the second moment look like?

**Edit 1:**

Following our definition of the moment generating function, we have that

$M_\mu(ix)=\exp(-|x|^\alpha)=\hat{\mu}(x)$

Now we know that the second momement is given by

$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}M_\mu(0)$.

Thus I have to compute $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}M_\mu(x)$. We do this by using the fourier transform, namely $\hat{\mu}''(x)$.

Am I correct? I just did a quick computation with wolfram and following that result I would get that $\hat{\mu}(0)''=0$ for $\alpha>2$. Why would the result follow from this?

Comment: It can be for $\alpha=2$ (if and only if). Can you look again at the question?

Comment: You are right! I forgot to add that $\alpha>2$. Sorry.

Comment: You should probably review your script. For example, $\Bbb{E}(X)=\hat{f}'(0)$ (up to constants which depend on the exact definition of the Fourier transform you are using). A similar formula holds for higher moments.

Comment: Hint: What would the second moment look like?

Comment: @orangeskid how do you see the iff so easily?? This is not clear to me at all.

Comment: I don't know if this is related to the question (since I'm not sure what properties to expect), so take it or leave it: If $0<\alpha\leq 2$ then the Fouriertransform of $\exp(-|x|^\alpha)$ is strictly positive (I think this is due to Levy). If $\alpha>2$, then the Fouriertransform has zeros (I think this is due to Polya).

Comment: @Did I had a look now at the second moment. Still I rather having difficulties to understand why this should explain the problem...

Comment: Look at the power series expansion of a Fourier transform of a positive function. Compare it with the power series expansion of $\exp(-|x|^{\alpha})$. In particular, the coefficient of $x^2$.

Comment: *Hint 2.* What can you say about $X$ when $\Bbb{E}[X^{2}] = 0$?

Comment: @sos440 If $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=0$, it follows that the random variable $X$ is constant. However, the probability distribution of a random variable $X$ is given by the Dirac-measure. We know that the Fourier transform of the latter is given by $\widehat{\delta_c}(x)=e^{i<x,c>}$. Due to the uniqueness of the Fourier transform of a distribution it follows that $\exp(-|x|^\alpha)$ is not the Fourier transform of a probability distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the definition of the moment generating function, we have that

$M_\mu(ix)=\exp(-|x|^\alpha)=\hat{\mu}(x)$,

where $\hat{\mu}$ denotes the Fourier transform of the measure $\mu$.

Now we know that the second moment is given by

$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}M_\mu(0)=\hat{\mu}''(0)$.

Thus we have to compute $\hat{\mu}''(x)$:

$$\hat{\mu}'(x)=\alpha x(-e^{-|x|^\alpha})|x|^{\alpha-2}\implies\hat{\mu}'(0)=0$$
$$\hat{\mu}''(x)=\alpha^2x^2e^{-|x|^\alpha}|x|^{2\alpha-4}+(\alpha-2)\alpha x^2(-e^{-|x|^\alpha})|x|^{\alpha-4}-\alpha e^{-|x|^\alpha}|x|^{\alpha-2}\overset{\alpha>2}{\implies}\hat{\mu}''(0)=0$$

Thus for a random variable $X$ with $X\sim\mu$, we have that $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=0$ and $\mathbb{E}(X)=0$. It follows that $\operatorname{Var}(X)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-[\mathbb{E}(X)]^2=0$. Now we know that $$\operatorname{Var}(X)=0\implies\mathbb{E}(X)=X \text{ a.s.}$$
Thus $X$ is a constant random variable. However, the probability measure of a constant random variable is given by the Dirac measure. We know that the Fourier transform of the latter is given by $\widehat{\delta_c}(x)=e^{i<x,c>}$ with constant $c$. Due to the uniqueness of the Fourier transform of a measure, it follows that $\exp(−|x|^\alpha)$ is not the Fourier transform of a probability distribution.

Comment: Nice. You should probably mention where the hypothesis that $\alpha\gt2$ is used.